# Because Paul (Saul) was part of the Sanhedrin was he required to be married?

Tags: paul-apostle

Because Paul (Saul) was a member of the sanhedrin was he required to be married?

Comment: Why do you think that Saul of Tarsus was part of the Sanhedrin? Why do you think that members of the Sanhedrin had to be married?

Comment: Pretty sure he is commissioned by them, and sides with the 'Pharisees' against the Sadducees, but is most likely never a member of the Sanhedrin. (Acts 23:6)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  When you have a moment, please take our Tour to find out how to ask a well researched and acceptable answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour